# Calculation of a spread light on a surface

Tags: calculus, geometry, physics

Suppose we have a light of power $P$ distributed on a plane $(x,y)$.
The distribution of the power is of the form:
$$P=f(x,y)$$
If we have a lens conjugating every point of the plane $(x,y)$ in another plane $(X,Y)$ (focal plane) in a way that for every point in the plane $(x,y)$ we have a circle of radius $r$ in $(X,Y)$, what is the distribution of the power in $(X,Y)$?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave **amplitude** in the focal plane is the Fourier transform of the wave **amplitude** in the pupil plane of the lens $L$. Assuming we are dealing with a diffraction-limited lens, the relationship between object amplitude $A_o$ and image amplitude $A_i$ is thus a convolution:

$$A_i(x,y) = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} dx' dy' \, L(x',y') A_o(x-x',y-y')$$

Note that $A_0(x,y) = \sqrt{f(x,y)} e^{i \phi(x,y)}$, where $\phi$ is some undetermined phase function - it could be a constant or zero, but it might not be.  (This may be specified or determined through experiment.)  The power distribution in the conjugate plane would then be $|A_i(x,y)|^2$.

Comment: I understand you supposed the lens 'focuses' the light of a point in the object plane in a point on the image plane. In this case, the focal plane isn't located in the focus of the lens; it's defocused. What changes in your analysis?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: Not much.  Defocus introduces a quadratric (or more complicated for faster lenses) phase variation in the lens function $L$.  The expression in general remains the same.  This is true even in the presence of reasonably small lens aberrations.